# Distance between 2 pixels

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Coming from software development, i'm new to image processing.
I try to get the distance between two pixels in an image that is a numpy array of shape (100, 100, 3).

For example i want to find the distance between a pixel blue (0, 0, 255) and a pixel red (255, 0, 0) in the image, I tried with a for loop or np.where() ... but no success.
The distance could be the some kind of difference between the two indexes in the image (possibility that there is more pixels of these colors so at least the first met in the image)

Any idea how to do that ?

EDIT:
I'm capturing part of my screen like that:

```
screen = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(80,120,100,100)))
```

Now i want to find the pixel(s) of color blue and the pixel(s) of color red and the distance between them in the image

Comment: Try to reshape your `ndarray` to be of shape `(10000, 3)`, and then apply pdist (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) from scipy package.

Comment: The color doesn't matter, use the position.

Comment: Are you first finding (or looking for) a pixel that is blue and a pixel that is red, before finding the distance between those pixels, and failing to find blue and red pixels?

Comment: with distance you mean like measuring the distance between two points on a sheet of paper? Have a look at 2d distance in euclidean vector space: sqrt((a.x-b.x)^2 + (a.y-b.y)^2)

Comment: Please show us the code that doesn't work... maybe it helps understand what you are trying to accomplish. What kind of distance do you need? Are we talking about spatial distances or color distances?

Comment: I need to first find the position(s) of these pixels if they exist in my image

Comment: Assuming that you are storing your image as [X,Y,Color], if you search for the first pixel that is blue (i.e. where the third dimension is [0,0,255]) and a pixel that is red (i.e. where the third dimension is [255,0,0]), then when you have found either pixel you should have their x,y coordinates too. Using the x,y coords of each pixel you can apply the euclidean distance formula.

Comment: Will you only have one pixel of these colors in the image, or could there be multiple? If there are multiple, how do you want to select which to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with a test image. It is 400x300 pixels of gray(192), with:

- a red 3x3 square at 20,10,
- a blue 3x3 square at 300,200

[image]

Now do this:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
import math

# Load image and ensure RGB - just in case palettised
im=Image.open("a.png").convert("RGB")

# Make numpy array from image
npimage=np.array(im)

# Describe what a single red pixel looks like
red=np.array([255,0,0],dtype=np.uint8)

# Find [x,y] coordinates of all red pixels
reds=np.where(np.all((npimage==red),axis=-1))
```

This gives:

```
(array([10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12]),
 array([20, 21, 22, 20, 21, 22, 20, 21, 22]))
```

Now let's do the blue pixels:

```
# Describe what a single blue pixel looks like
blue=np.array([0,0,255],dtype=np.uint8)

# Find [x,y] coordinates of all blue pixels
blues=np.where(np.all((npimage==blue),axis=-1))
```

This gives:

```
(array([200, 200, 200, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202]),
 array([300, 301, 302, 300, 301, 302, 300, 301, 302]))
```

So now we need the distance from the first red to the first blue pixel

```
dx2 = (blues[0][0]-reds[0][0])**2          # (200-10)^2
dy2 = (blues[1][0]-reds[1][0])**2          # (300-20)^2
distance = math.sqrt(dx2 + dy2)
```